redirection to the main page after logIn or registration doesn't working. firebase, private route, email authentication
I encountered an issue that I can't solve. In my handleLogIn function within the ContextProvider component, I am using the useNavigate hook to redirect the page to "/" if the user successfully logs in. However, after the user successfully logs in, they are not redirected to the main page; instead, they are redirected back to the login page. After the second form submission, the page redirection works correctly.
How can I redirect the user from the "/sign-in" or "/sign-up" page immediately after form submission?
here is my contextProviderComponent:
export const ContextAPI = createContext<null | TContextAPI>(null);

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.User | undefined | null>(undefined);
  const [currentUserId, setCurrentUserId] = useState<string | undefined | null>(undefined);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { signUpValues, SignUpInputConstructor, handleRegister, signUpError } = useAuth();
  const { logInValues, SignInInputConstructor } = useLogIn();
  const { handleLogout, logOutError } = useLogOut();
  const { newGroupName, isShowGroupCreator, setIsShowGroupCreator, setNewGroupName } = useGroupMenu();

  const handleUserGroups = () => {
    if (currentUserId) {
      const groupRef = doc(db, `/user_groups/${currentUserId}/${newGroupName}`, uuid());
      if (newGroupName === "" || newGroupName.length > 20) {
        console.log("group name is incorrect");
      } else {
        setDoc(groupRef, { merge: true });
        console.log("db updated sucessfully");
        navigate("/");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("currentUserId is not set");
    }
  };

  const [logInError, setLogInError] = useState<string>("");
  const logIn = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  const handleLogIn = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(logInValues.email)) {
      return setLogInError("email is not correct");
    }
    if (logInValues.password === "") {
      return setLogInError("password field can not be empty");
    } else {
      try {
        setLogInError("");
        setLoading(true);
        logIn(logInValues.email, logInValues.password).then(() => {
          navigate("/");
        });
      } catch (errors) {
        setLogInError("Failed to log-in in account");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const vals: TContextAPI = {
    setNewGroupName,
    isShowGroupCreator,
    setIsShowGroupCreator,

    newGroupName,
    currentUserId,
    handleUserGroups,
    handleLogout,
    logOutError,
    setLoading,
    currentUser,
    signUpValues,
    SignUpInputConstructor,
    handleRegister,
    loading,
    signUpError,
    logInValues,
    SignInInputConstructor,
    handleLogIn,
    logInError,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
      setCurrentUserId(user?.uid || null);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return <ContextAPI.Provider value={vals}> {!loading && children} </ContextAPI.Provider>;
};

and this is my LogIn component:
const LogIn = () => {
  const SignInInputConstructor = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.SignInInputConstructor);
  const loading = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.loading);
  const currentUser = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.currentUser);
  const handleLogIn = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.handleLogIn);
  const logInError = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.logInError);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Log In page</h1>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          handleLogIn?.(e);
        }}
      >
        {currentUser?.email}
        {logInError && <Alert severity="error">{logInError}</Alert>}
        {SignInInputConstructor?.map((item) => (
          <>
            <Typography>{item.typography}</Typography>
            <TextField
              id={item.id}
              placeholder={item.placeholder}
              variant={item.variant}
              value={item.value}
              onChange={item.onChange}
            />
          </>
        ))}
        <Button variant="contained" type="submit" disabled={loading}>
          Log In
        </Button>
        <Typography>
          Need an account? <Link to={"/sign-up"}>Sign Up</Link>
        </Typography>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

and this is my privateRoute component:
const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const currentUser = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.currentUser);
  if (currentUser === undefined) return null;

  return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/sign-in" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;

and the lastone is my main component with all routes:
const Main = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/sign-in",
            element: <LogIn />,
          },
          {
            path: "/sign-up",
            element: <Register />,
          },
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <PrivateRoute />,
            children: [
              {
                path: "/",
                element: <GroupMenu />,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: "/add-group",
                    element: <AddGroupModal />,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                path: "/group-content",
                element: <GroupContent />,
              },
              {
                path: "/dashboard",
                element: <Dashboard />,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    { basename: "/thatswhy_items_counter/" }
  );

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

If you need more details, here is the project repo on GitHub: repo-link
Thanks to all of you for your help in advance!
I've tried to move my login functions from the custom login hook to the ContextProvider component. I've tried to manage the conditional loading state in the PrivateRoute component. I've also tried to update my currentUser state in the logIn function within the ContextProvider component. Unfortunately, it didn't help me. I think I have this issue because my logIn function needs more time to log in the user, and my handleLogIn function doesn't wait.
log-in issue gif

I see no overt issues with your frontend code so I suspect this might be more of a timing issue where auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword resolves and returns (and navigates) before auth.onAuthStateChanged has picked up that the auth state changed. The .then should delay the navigation at least a render cycle. Think you could create a running Codesandbox of your code that reproduces the problem that we could inspect live?

@DrewReese
hier is Codesandbox of my code: Edit counter auth issue

You've declared your router within the ReactTree, so when the component rerenders for any reason, router is redeclared and unmounts the old routing tree and mounts the new one, and this interrupts any active navigation actions.
Move the router declaration out of the ReactTree.
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/sign-in",
        element: <LogIn />,
      },
      {
        path: "/sign-up",
        element: <Register />,
      },
      {
        element: <PrivateRoute />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <GroupMenu />,
            children: [
              {
                path: "/add-group",
                element: <AddGroupModal />,
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            path: "/group-content",
            element: <GroupContent />,
          },
          {
            path: "/dashboard",
            element: <Dashboard />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

Or memoize it so it can be provided as a stable reference.
const Main = () => {
  const router = useMemo(createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <App />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/sign-in",
          element: <LogIn />,
        },
        {
          path: "/sign-up",
          element: <Register />,
        },
        {
          element: <PrivateRoute />,
          children: [
            {
              path: "/",
              element: <GroupMenu />,
              children: [
                {
                  path: "/add-group",
                  element: <AddGroupModal />,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "/group-content",
              element: <GroupContent />,
            },
            {
              path: "/dashboard",
              element: <Dashboard />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]), []);
  
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

I recommend also converting your handleLogIn callback to an async function so you can await the logIn to resolve and manage the loading state better, i.e. to set loading false only after the log-in attempt has succeeded or failed.
const handleLogIn = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(logInValues.email)) {
    return setLogInError("email is not correct");
  }
  if (logInValues.password === "") {
    return setLogInError("password field can not be empty");
  }

  try {
    setLogInError("");
    setLoading(true);

    await logIn(logInValues.email, logInValues.password);

    navigate("/");
  } catch (errors) {
    setLogInError("Failed to log-in in account");
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

There still appears to be a bit of a synchronization issue between when logIn, or auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword, successfully authenticates a user and when Firebase can push an auth change to your onAuthStateChange listener which updates the currentUser state client-side.
Here's a couple additional things you can try:

Capture the userCredential.user (see UserCredential) value from the resolved signInWithEmailAndPassword call and update the currentUser state.
const ContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.User | undefined | null>(undefined);

  ...

  const logIn = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  const handleLogIn = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(logInValues.email)) {
      return setLogInError("email is not correct");
    }
    if (logInValues.password === "") {
      return setLogInError("password field can not be empty");
    }

    try {
      setLogInError("");
      setLoading(true);

      const userCredential = await logIn(logInValues.email, logInValues.password);
      setCurrentUser(userCredential.user);

      navigate("/");
    } catch (errors) {
      setLogInError("Failed to log-in in account");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

...


Place the navigate call to the back of the Javascript event queue. Note that this is a bit of a hack, but by delaying the navigate call it allows Javascript to process any other additional enqueued callbacks to process first, then issue the navigation action.
const handleLogIn = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(logInValues.email)) {
    return setLogInError("email is not correct");
  }
  if (logInValues.password === "") {
    return setLogInError("password field can not be empty");
  }

  try {
    setLogInError("");
    setLoading(true);

    await logIn(logInValues.email, logInValues.password);

    setTimeout(() => navigate("/"));
  } catch (errors) {
    setLogInError("Failed to log-in in account");
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};




Thank you very much for your answer. The improvements you offered were very useful and made my code better. Unfortunately, my problem wasn't solved. If the user is not logged in, they still have to submit the log-in form twice to be redirected to the "/" page. I've noticed that, for some reason, after the first submission, the user is redirected to the "/" page and then redirected back to the "/sign-in" page. The second submission allows the user to stay on the "/" page after submitting the form. I've added a "log-in issue gif" as a visual explanation below my question.

@dimonchik11 Like I said, it seems to be a timing issue between when one API returns that a user has successfully authenticated, and the onAuthStateChanged listener picking it up. You are issuing the navigation action between the two. Let me update with a couple additional suggestions.

thank you very much for your help. Delaying the navigate call helped me to get rid of this issue. It's really weird because I had already tried putting the navigate call into the .then() method, and it used to call navigate("/") at the end of all enqueued callbacks. But now it works, and I really appreciate it.

@dimonchik11 That is because even though it was a Promise chain the code was still all synchronous, i.e. no await was encountered, so the chain was processed synchronously to completion and the function returned and then the rest of the enqueued callbacks are processed by Javascript, including the React state update. I hope this made sense in spite of being a bit hand-wavey.
